clear IME input onfocus in Javascript
Currently I'm having problems with IME.
I am designing a chat and messaging application with Vue3. I use a div with :editcontenable="true" as input. Everything was ok but there was a problem when I used Japanese. After I press the send message button and focus again on the input. The keyboard hint bar is not removed even though I have set input.innerHtml="". Because of that. When I enter any character, the input does not recognize that character and the focus is lost.
If you know about this problem, please help me. Thanks
